# Input number field not sending keypress event on Enter button press (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, keypress

As the title states:

For an `<input type="number">` field, the **Go** or **Enter** button of a mobile keyboard (tested on Chrome Android 5.1) doesn't send a keypress event when clicked.

Regular text inputs allow sending keycode `13` when then button is clicked.

In my opinion this seems like a major bug in Android.

Any ideas to omit this non-behavior? I'd like to catch enter events on a number input to auto-submit the form...